# Maternity in Sweden, on short notice

Tags: eu-citizens, marriage, sweden, children, benefits

I have a postdoc position in Sweden starting January next year, and signed the contract already. My fiance and I (we're both German nationals) planned to move to Sweden, me in January, she by the end of the year, and planned to stay there prospectively, provided she can find a job as well, and then slowly start thinking about starting a family. We planned to get married sometime in September.

As life goes, the doctor told us today that if we ever want to have kids, it has to be now or never, so she might move there with me beginning 2017. My question is what the situation would be for her, insurance-wise and in terms of maternity services and benefits, especially since she'd be moving there without a job offer or prior residence under her belt.

Comment: How are you getting medical coverage? Would she also be covered if you married before moving?

Comment: Since I have employment through a Swedish employer, I will get a "personnummer" and thus be eligible for healthcare. She might get one too in either case (married or engaged), but in some countries you have to proof residence for a certain amount of time before you're eligible for maternity benefits etc.

Comment: You need to find out if there's a reciprocal agreement with between your country (unspecified) and Sweden and add it to your question.

Comment: How's my country unspecified, it literally says we're both German in the second sentence.

Comment: @user32849: I know this is splitting hairs, but you can be German but also be *resident* in some other country at the same time. The distinction can be important in questions like this.

Comment: Got it, but since we'll be living in Sweden the only other country that matters would be that corresponding to our nationality.